# How to add Spark-excel to PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to read xlsx to PySpark and tried with multiple ways to import the library of Spark-excel but I still get errors while reading xlsx file.
I'm using Spark with standalone mode on my Mac.

My code:

```py
# spark configuration
spark_path = "/spark/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7"
findspark.init(spark_path)
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("Word Count").config("--packages com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.12:0.13.7").getOrCreate()

data_location = "bank_transactions.xlsx"
df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").load(data_location)
```

I got the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o37.load.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.Utils$MapIncluding.<init>(Utils.scala:9)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.WorkbookReader$.<init>(WorkbookReader.scala:31)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.WorkbookReader$.<clinit>(WorkbookReader.scala)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:28)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:18)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:12)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:297)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:286)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:232)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Product$class
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 23 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solutions:

1. Download proper spark-excel library, for me it's:
   https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.crealytics/spark-excel_2.12/0.13.7
2. Create directory `spark_jars` in the SPARK_HOME then store the `spark-excel` package in `spark_jars` directory
3. Add the `spark_jars` to `spark.executor.extraClassPath` of Spark session:

```py
findspark.init(spark_path)
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local") \
    .appName("Word Count") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages","com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.12:0.13.7") \
    .getOrCreate()
spark
```

Comment: Hi, this will work on windows too ? what is spark_path ? is it the path to spark directory ?

Comment: spark_path is home directory of Spark. For example, if you install Spark on /opt/spark. Then you use findspark.init("/opt/spark") to make your python session available to submit job.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the update.  steps I follow on Windows are below:https://github.com/MRafiqAsim/sparkexcelreading/

Answer (score 2):

**Steps to follow to configure windows enviroment to read/write Exel file using spark excel and jupyter notebook with anaconda navigator.**

**Step 1**
Install Anaconda Navigator

**Step 2**
Download Spark from Spark website (version 3.3.2). https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html

**Step 3**
Download Hadoop and winutil.exe from github For winutils I copied files from this github repository: https://github.com/cdarlint/winutils I used files from : hadoop-3.2.2/bin

**Step 4**
unzip spark to C:\spark inside spark folder at c:\spark create directory "hadoop" and then inside hadoop directory create directory "bin" now copy paste all the files from step 2 "hadoop-3.2.2/bin" to "c:\spark\hadoop\bin"

**Step 5**
install JDK 11 if not installed.

**Step 6**
Enviroment variables: Set the following enviroment variables :

- SPARK_HOME="C:\spark" (In users and systems variables)
- HADOOP_HOME="%SPARK_HOME%\hadoop" (In users and systems variables)
- PYSPARK_PYTHON="python"
- PYTHONPATH="%SPARK_HOME%\python;%SPARK_HOME%\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip;%PYTHONPATH%"
  (In users and systems variables)
- In Users and Systems PATH variables add this to Path "C:\spark\bin"

**Step 7**
open Anaconda CMD prompt and cd to c:\spark

**Step 8**

- run "bin\pyspark --master local[3] --driver-memory 2g --packages
  com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.12:3.3.1_0.18.5"
- it will create a file in users hidden directory ie
  "C:\Users\user_name.ivy2\jars"

Copy all the jar files from this folder and paste in "C:\spark\jars"

**Step 9**
Close Anaconda Navigator

**Step 10**
Open Anaconda Navigator and launch the notebook

**Step 11**
now the Excel reading spark-excel will work.

**Step 12 Sample File read**

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
sc  = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession(sc)
df = spark.read.format('com.crealytics.spark.excel').option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load(r"C:\\Users\\abc\\myfile.xlsx\")
df.show()
```